# react native run-ios or run-android error

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native

i'm trying to use this project

https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-listview

I'll write down the order processing.

1. download the project.zip & unzipping
2. in terminal, i used this command [npm install]
3. and this [react-native run-android] & [react-native run-ios]

but i was failed to build this project.

open-ui-iMac:react-native-gifted-listview-master openobject$ react-native run-android
Android project not found. Maybe run react-native android first?

open-ui-iMac:react-native-gifted-listview-master openobject$ react-native run-ios
/Users/openobject/practice/react-native-gifted-listview-master/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir

```
at Error (native)
at process.chdir (/Users/openobject/practice/react-native-gifted-listview-master/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:18:9)
at _runIOS (node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:50:11)
at node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:24:5
at tryCallTwo (/Users/openobject/practice/react-native-gifted-listview-master/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
at doResolve (/Users/openobject/practice/react-native-gifted-listview-master/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
at new Promise (/Users/openobject/practice/react-native-gifted-listview-master/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
at Array.runIOS (node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:23:10)
at Object.run (node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:95:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:88:7)
```

i found a few solution of this.

### they say "use this command"

rm -rf node_modules

rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*

watchman watch-del-all

### npm install --save react-native@latest

but it couldn't solve this problem

how i can solve this problem?

Comment: The step is not clear. Did you have `react-native` project prior to downloading this project? Note that this is not a full `react-native` project. This is a `Component` which can be installed to `react-native's` project to show a `listview`.

Comment: then, i just put this folder inside project folder? i'll try this. thanks

Comment: Nope. That wont work. I'll post steps on how to do it the right way.

Comment: oh, thanks! i really confuse to build react-native project.

Comment: try gradlew clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a 3rd party React Native Component on your project. The right way to install and use the Component is as follow:

1. Get inside your `react-native` project: `cd yourProject`
2. On your **terminal** run the following code: `npm install react-native-gifted-listview --save`. This is the way to install **Components**. `npm install component-name --save`
3. Import the installed component inside your page where you want to use: `import GiftedListView from 'react-native-gifted-listview';`
4. Now you can use the component:

```js
<GiftedListView
  rowView={this._renderRowView}
  onFetch={this._onFetch}
  firstLoader={true} 
  pagination={true} 
  refreshable={true} 
  withSections={false}
  refreshableTintColor="blue"
/>
```

Comment: omg. this is work perfectly.
really really thank you! Thank you become learn a lot of things.